# How to resolve this circular dependency in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency, es6-class

I am trying to use static classes in React. However, I keep getting the following error when running the Webpack server locally: `Uncaught TypeError: _util_stageHelper__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.getStageName is not a function`. I have traced this down to a cyclic dependency in my code.

Here's the structure of my code:

```
// util/stageHelper.js
import {StageConfiguration} from '../config/StageConfiguration'
export class StageEligibility {
    static stageEnabled = StageConfiguration.getEnabled();

    static isEligible(key) {
        if(stageEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        return key.indexOf('com') > -1;
    }

    static notifyEligibility() {
        if (!this.stageEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        alert('Only the com stages are eligible for viewing');
    }

    // other other static properties and functions
}

export const getStageName = (key) => {
    if (StageEligibility.isEligible(key)) {
        return STAGES[key];
    }
};


// config/StageConfiguration.js
import {getStageName} from '../util/stageHelper'

export class StageConfiguration {
    static config = {
        stageName: getStageName('com-openserve') // the code breaks here with the above error
        enabled: true,
    }
    static getEnabled() {
        return this.config.enabled;
    }
    // static properties and functions that make use of this.config
}
```

I import `StageEligibility` in a root React component in my application and call `StageEligibility.notifyEligibility()`.

Could someone please provide some ideas on how I can resolve this circular dependency?

Comment: Separate from the problem you've asked about, you have an error in `isEligible`: you're using an undeclared free variable in it called `stageEnabled`. There isn't one in scope. You'd want `this.stageEnabled` or `StageEligibility.stageEnabled`.

Comment: What's the code for `StageConfiguration.getEnabled`?

Comment: Apologies, the code was too complex to post here so I tried simplifying it as much as possible to present my problem. I have added this method which just returns the appropriate config (it does some other stuff too but this is not relevant to the question).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my answer doesn't have to change based on that code, but good to have it there.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, when you have a cycle between modules A and B it means that without careful planning of the loading order (which can be tricky), you can't use resources imported from A in B's top-level code, or resources imported from B in A's top-level code. But your `static` property initializers are trying to do just that.

The problem in this specific case looks more fundamental than modules. You have `StageConfiguration` trying to use `getStageName` as the class is created, and `getStageName` tries to use the `StageEligibility` class, which tries to use `StageConfiguration`. You can't have the creation of class `StageConfiguration` rely on `StageEligibility` already existing and being fully initialized **and** have the creation of `StageEligibility` rely on `StageConfiguration` already existing and being fully initialized. That's a chicken-and-egg logical problem.

Extract the parts that both classes need into a third class/function/data member that each class can use indepdendently, so that that class/function/data member can be created and initialized, and then used as part of creating each of the classes.